# Export to Excel holding file open, and not exporting first datagrid

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I am trying to export 2 datagridviews to excel but it is missing the last line of data for both of the sets of data grid views, I have checked the code and I cant see what I have done wrong? Also it is creating a temporary file when exporting and then locking the file and not exiting gracefully and only a reboot allows you to delete the file? Any help would be great code is below. For example if i save as test.xlsx I get 2 files ~$test.xlsx and test.xlsx and both both files are locked.

```
  private void exprtbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
        try
        {

            // creating new Excelsheet in workbook
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet1 = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet2 = null;

            // get the reference of first sheet. By default its name is Sheet1.
            // store its reference to worksheet
            worksheet1 = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
            worksheet1 = workbook.ActiveSheet;

            // changing the name of active sheet
            worksheet1.Name = "Switch Totals";


            // storing header part in Excel
            for (int i = 1; i < switchtotalgrd.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                worksheet1.Cells[1, i] = switchtotalgrd.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
            }

            // storing Each row and column value to excel sheet
            for (int i = 0; i < switchtotalgrd.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < switchtotalgrd.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    worksheet1.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = switchtotalgrd.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
            // Adding second worksheet
            int count = workbook.Worksheets.Count;
            Excel.Worksheet addedSheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing,
            workbook.Worksheets[count], Type.Missing, Type.Missing);


            // get the reference of first sheet. By default its name is Sheet1.
            // store its reference to worksheet
            worksheet2 = workbook.Sheets["Sheet2"];
            worksheet2 = workbook.ActiveSheet;

            // changing the name of active sheet
            worksheet2.Name = "Itemised Extn";


            // storing header part in Excel
            for (int i = 1; i < fullresult.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                worksheet2.Cells[1, i] = fullresult.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
            }

            // storing Each row and column value to excel sheet

            for (int i = 0; i < fullresult.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < fullresult.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (fullresult.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value == null)
                    {
                        fullresult.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = "NA";
                    }
                    worksheet2.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = fullresult.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                }
            }

            // save the application
            string fileName = String.Empty;
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel files |*.xls|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
            saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                fileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                workbook.SaveAs(fileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            }
            else
                return;
        }
            //Catch all errors.
        catch (System.Exception)
        { 
        }
        finally
        {
            workbook = null;
            app = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably might want to double-check your outer for loop again, e.g. `for (int i = 0; i < fullresult.Rows.Count - 1; i++)`, shouldn't it be using less than and equal perhaps?

Since you are using Excel com interop, you will need to call this method to be able to release the resource after you are done with it, [Marshal.ReleaseComObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

A good practice is to use **try{...}catch{...}finally{...}**, and release com object in the finally block.

Comment: Thank you yes setting it to <= fixed it. Just need to work out still why its being locked.